# Vim: word wrap for documents

Tags: vim, documents

What's the best way to do word wrapping for a document in `vim`?
I'd like have each line wrap at 80 characters, not just visually wrap but enter a newline.

I got this kind of working by using

```
:set wrap
:set linebreak
```

But if I go back and insert text on a previous line, it doesn't adjust the rest of the paragraph.  It takes the overflow text and puts it on a newline, but the line that comes after doesn't get moved up to fill in the gap.

So if I edit a previous line, my paragraph can look like this

```
A line that is 80 characters long
short line
A line that is 80 characters lone
```

I want it to be like this:

```
A line that is 80 characters long
short line A line that is 80
characters long
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`wrap` and `linebreak` control the display of text, I think you'll find they don't actually insert newlines in the file. To get vim to insert newlines in the file as you type, set `textwidth` to the desired width (e.g. 80).

That will still not automatically reflow subsequent lines when you insert more text. I usually do that manually with `gq}`, but I just discovered that `set formatoptions+=a` will tell vim to do it automatically. See [the help for `auto-format`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#auto-format).

Comment: `formatoptions+=a` is very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `gq}` wraps a paragraph to `textwidth`. Be sure to `set tw=80` first. Many distros map that to Q. So you may also be able to also use `Q}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use `par` for formatting, it can even word wrap with an existing prefix, in the context of emails for example.