# Avoid reformatting bullet lists with formatoptions+=a

Tags: vim, markdown

I am using Vim with `formatoptions +=a` as described in [Vim: word wrap for documents](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10182/vim-word-wrap-for-documents) to format lines automatically while I write documents, expecially Markdown documents.

My problem is that Vim wants to reformat also bullet lists because there is blank line between each bullet point.

What happes is that vim reformats

```
This is wath we will do:

* task 1,
* task 2,
* task 3.
```

into

```
This is wath we will do:

* task 1,   task 2,   task 3.
```

(I also do not understand why the asterisks disappear in this reformatting process.)

How can I make Vim stop reformatting these lists?

Comment: The asterisks disappear because Vim mistaken them for comments leaders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

- add `n` to `formatoptions` so vim recognizes lists (`:set fo+=n`)
- set the `formatlistpat` option to recognize asterisk as bullets (`set flp+=\\\|^\\*\\s*`) (note that number of backslashes depends on your `magic`ness level).

It's not perfect based on my testing but it seems to be close.

Answer (score 2):

Is the `filetype` option set to `markdown` when you are editing your Markdown files? You can use `:verbose set filetype?` to inspect the current value.

When you have run `:filetype plugin on` (e.g. from your `.vimrc`), and `filetype` is set to `markdown`, Vim will source [`$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim`](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/ftplugin/markdown.vim) which will set some options (`comments`, `formatlistpat`, and `formatoptions`) that should help with formatting Markdown list items.

Note: The common Markdown filename pattern `*.md` is actually mapped to the `modula2` filetype by [`$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/filetype.vim). You may want to override this setting if you commonly use this filename pattern for your Markdown files. You could do that by putting this in your `.vimrc` file:

```
autocmd! filetypedetect BufNewFile,BufRead *.md setfiletype markdown
```

Alternatively, you could add a [modeline](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#modeline) to each file:

```
<!-- vim: set filetype=markdown : -->
```

Comment: tpope's syntax files (the one I am using) set formatlistpath in https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/blob/master/ftplugin/markdown.vim . For some reasons it looks that the ftplugin is not loaded...

Comment: That `vim-markdown` plugin should be sufficient, but you need to enable its functionality (and that of other filetype plugins) with `:filetype plugin on`. See [`:help :filetype-plugin-on`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#%3Afiletype-plugin-on).